# iMessages app keeps displaying a "syncing with iCloud", how to disable it?

Tags: mac, messages

On my Mac, the iMessages app keeps displaying a "syncing with iCloud" notification frequently. How can I turn this off?

Note, I do not wish to turn off syncing. I also vaguely remember there is a keyboard shortcut to do this, I forgot what it was...

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Did you try toggling Enable Message in iCloud checkmark under Preferences → iMessage?